# Checking input data types in pydantic

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

Is there a way to check the datatypes of the input variables natively in pydantic, like:

```
class ModelParameters(BaseModel):
    str_val: str
    int_val: int
    wrong_val: int


test = ModelParameters(**dict({
    "str_val":"test",
    "int_val":1,
    "wrong_val":1.2}))
```

Which should throw an error for `wrong_val`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### v2.0 Edit:

Pydantic's behaviour has changed with the release of **version 2.0**. **Now the example given will raise an error for `wrong_val`**, as expected.

Compared to pydantic 1.x as exposed below, v2.x also doesn't parse an int like `123` into a `"123"` str anymore if the attribute type is `str`.

---

**For pydantic 1.x** (original answer)

Pydantic does a handful of implicit conversion, particularly on primitive types like int, str, or float. The reason behind this behaviour is discussed [here](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/578).

So indeed, with a class like this:

```py
class ModelParameters(BaseModel):
    str_val: str
    int_val: int
    wrong_val: int
```

You can absolutely instantiate an object like that:

```py
test = ModelParameters(**dict({
    "str_val": 123,
    "int_val": "1",
    "wrong_val": 1.2}))

test
# ModelParameters(str_val='123', int_val=1, wrong_val=1)
```

**But you *do* have the option to enforce type checking.** What you need to do, is to use `StrictStr`, `StrictFloat` and `StrictInt` as a type-hint replacement for str, float and int. You'll find them in `pydantic.types`. In your case:

```py
from pydantic.types import StrictStr, StrictInt

class ModelParameters(BaseModel):
    str_val: StrictStr
    int_val: StrictInt
    wrong_val: StrictInt
```

Now, if you try the same instantiation, you'll see validation errors all around the place, like you'd expect:

```py
test = ModelParameters(**dict({
    "str_val": 123,
    "int_val": "1",
    "wrong_val": 1.2}))
```

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for ModelParameters
str_val
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
int_val
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
wrong_val
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```